# Is any way to update a long in Firebase without get it in a variable?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I look for a way to do this:

```
long var = var + x
```

but do it directly on firebase.

For the moment i get the value in a variable first, then change the variable, and finally update firebase... but if there is a way to do it with less code there was great!

This is the way i am doing now and works fine:

```
long var = 0;
mFirestone.collection("col").document("doc").get()

      var = documentSnapshot.getLong("FirestoneValue");

var = var + x;

Map<String, Object> updateHashMap = new HashMap<>();
updateHashMap.put("FirestoneValue", var);

mFirestone.collection("col").document("doc").update(updateHashMap);
```

Thank you a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is possible with Firestore's `increment` operator. See the Firestore documentation on [incrementing a numerical value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), which contains this example for Java/Android:

```
DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update("population", FieldValue.increment(50));
```